# Sql Many to many query ask

Tags: java, mysql, sql, many-to-many

### product

id_product
productName
componentID

### component

componentdID
nameofComponent

what i have here is a list of products that are gonna be in Combobox and on the right it's gonna be jtable in which i need when i pick a product it lists all components that are needed to make that product. How do i make sql query in selectProduct.
Also to mention 1 product can have up to 100 components. And There is atleast 50 products

Thanks

Comment: Ya gonna need anuvva table - product_component

Comment: a littbe bit more info would be nice but i found anova table

Comment: Your product table contains the componentid so a simple join should do.

Answer (score 0):

and you should avoid the direct use on componetId in product table avoid unusefulf replication of product for mantain the relation with componenent

for this 
You could create a specific table for mantain the relation between products and components eg:

```
 table product_component ( id, product_id, componentdID  )
```

then you can select the component of a product as

```
 select a.productName, b.nameofComponent 
 from product_component  c 
 inner join product a on a.product_id = c.product_id
 inner join  component b on b.componentdID   = c.componentdID
```

and for a specific product

```
 select a.productName, b.nameofComponent 
 from product_component  c 
 inner join product a on a.product_id = c.product_id
 inner join  component b on b.componentdID   = c.componentdID 
 where a.product_id = your_product_id_value
```

Comment: not sure this is necessary componentid is already in product table for some reason.

Comment: And how would i relate them how would i selectfrom them to get what i need, im new in programming and also in sql so syntax would be great :D

Comment: @Alex  . answer  added  a brief suggestion too